# Removing parentheses from a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'd like to remove all parentheses from a set of strings running through a loop. The best way that I've seen this done is with the use of preg_replace(). However, I am having a hard time understanding the pattern parameter.

The following is the loop

```
    $coords= explode (')(', $this->input->post('hide'));
        foreach ($coords as $row)
        {
            $row = trim(preg_replace('/\*\([^)]*\)/', '', $row));
            $row = explode(',',$row);
            $lat = $row[0];
            $lng = $row[1];
        }
```

And this is the value of 'hide'.

```
    (1.4956873362063747, 103.875732421875)(1.4862491569669245, 103.85856628417969)(1.4773257504016037, 103.87968063354492)
```

That pattern is wrong as far as i know. i got it from another thread, i tried to read about patterns but couldn't get it. I am rather short on time so I posted this here while also searching for other ways in other parts of the net. Can someone please supply me with the correct pattern for what I am trying to do? Or is there an easier way of doing this?

EDIT: Ah, just got how preg_replace() works. Apparently I misunderstood how it worked, thanks for the info.

Comment: what is the value of `$this->input->post('hide')`

Comment: How about just using `preg_replace('#[()]#',"",$this->input->post('hide'))`

Comment: post the example of the output you want

Answer (score 1):

I see you actually want to extract all the coordinates

If so, better use preg_match_all:

```
$ php -r '
preg_match_all("~\(([\d\.]+), ?([\d\.]+)\)~", "(654,654)(654.321, 654.12)", $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
'
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (654,654)
            [1] => 654
            [2] => 654
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => (654.321, 654.12)
            [1] => 654.321
            [2] => 654.12
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand entirely why you would need `preg_replace`. `explode()` removes the delimiters, so all you have to do is remove the opening and closing parantheses on the first and last string respectively. You can use `substr()` for that.

Get first and last elements of array:

```
$first = reset($array);
$last = end($array);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> "And this is the value of $coords."

If $coords is a string, your foreach makes no sense. If that string is your input, then:

```
$coords= explode (')(', $this->input->post('hide'));
```

This line removes the inner parentheses from your string, so your $coords array will be:

- (1.4956873362063747, 103.875732421875
- 1.4862491569669245, 103.85856628417969
- 1.4773257504016037, 103.87968063354492)

Answer (score 0):

The `pattern` parameter accepts a regular expression. The function returns a new string where all parts of the original that match the regex are replaced by the second argument, i.e. `replacement`

How about just using `preg_replace` on the original string?

```
preg_replace('#[()]#',"",$this->input->post('hide'))
```

To dissect your current regex, you are matching:

```
an asterisk character, 
followed by an opening parenthesis,
followed by zero or more instances of 
    any character but a closing parenthesis
followed by a closing parenthesis
```

Of course, this will never match, since exploding the string removed the closing and opening parentheses from the chunks.